# Using Metadata API to query

Tags: apex, metadata-api

As a beginner developer I've been given the task to get through Metadata API, the Custom Metadata Types objects and then make a query to get a list with the name (Label) of those *__mdt* objects. I've done some API trailheads, read over stackexchange advise, including the [Andrew Fawcett](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) classes but I'm still stuck in what should I do next.

The purpose of getting the Label names of the custom metadata type objects is to have a lightning component with 2 tables. One which lists all the *__mdt* objects and the other which opens the records of the object that is clicked. This should be done with a single soql apex class, not one soql for each *__mdt* object and, to do so, I've been instructed to do as I've explained above.

I have a basic understanding of how Apex works and can do the basics but this looks like unknown territory to me. Can anyone stir me in the right direction?

Grateful for any help,
Rui

Comment: This might not be related, but i have a gut feeling that you are looking for something like this.. https://github.com/forcedotcom/CustomMetadataLoader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try executing the following query:

```
Select MasterLabel, QualifiedApiName, KeyPrefix, DurableId 
From EntityDefinition 
Where IsCustomizable = true 
And QualifiedApiName Like '%_mdt'
```

This will retrieve all existing Custom Metadata that your org owns, with their Name, Api Name, Key Prefix and Id.

You can leverage the Key Prefix and Id to create redirection as described in your usecase:

- The Key Prefix concatenated with "?setupid=CustomMetadata" will redirect any user to the "Manage Records" page of the Custom Metadata Type.
- The Id will redirect to the Custom Metadata page.